# How to force window to activate in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have a menu bar application, so "Application is background only" is set to true. In appDelegate I have a function that creates an About window but for some reason I can't force the About window to become the current active window and have focus on it.

About button click 
[image: about button]
Created window
[image: after clicking image]

Only after clicking again (sometimes few times) to open the About window does the window become active. Clicking on it does not activate it, and the click next to it when it is already active, e.g. on a desktop, does not deactivate it.

After clicking About button again
[image: after clicking again]

How to force the window to be the active window after showing, and after clicking anywhere next to it, it was deactivated and after clicking on it again it became active again (similarly to the "About This Mac" window, for example)

```swift
@main
struct MenuBarApp: App {
  @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor var appDelegate: AppDelegate
  @StateObject var appState: AppState = AppState.shared

  var body: some Scene {
    MenuBarExtra("MenuBarApp", systemImage: "rectangle.and.text.magnifyingglass") {
      ContentView()
        .environmentObject(appState)
        .environmentObject(appDelegate)
    }.menuBarExtraStyle(.window)
  }
}
```

```swift
private var aboutWindowController: NSWindowController?

func showAboutWindow() {
  if aboutWindowController == nil {
    let window: NSWindow = NSWindow(
      contentRect: NSRect.zero,
      styleMask: [.closable, .titled, .fullSizeContentView],
      backing: .buffered,
      defer: false
    )

    window.title = "About Window"
    window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: AboutView())
    window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
    window.center()
    window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)

    aboutWindowController = NSWindowController(window: window)
  }

  aboutWindowController?.showWindow(aboutWindowController?.window)
}
```

Comment: What is the minimum macOS version you need to support? If this is macOS Ventura, you possibly can make it purely SwiftUI: you need to add a `WindowGroup { ... }`  or `Window {... }` in the body of `App`.You might look into WWDC '22 [Bring multiple windows to your SwiftUI app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10061/), if you not have already ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper

Currently, I have set minimum deployments to macos Sonoma (14.2), but I can reduce it if necessary.

Comment: So, you can make a pure SwiftUI app. I would suggest to follow the WWDC video which demonstrates very closely your use case with the "BookClub" app. Have a look! ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I watched this video but I already knew this solution and I would love to do it this way because it seems much cleaner and closer to the KISS method which I always try to stick to. The problem is that my window has a changed styleMask as in the question. And I haven't found a way to stick to the method in the video and change a few parameters of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the line

```
NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
```

or in macOS 14+

```
NSApp.activate()
```

after the `showWindow` line

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, I've already tried this and the window appears above all other windows and becomes active for a split second and then stays on top but goes inactive

Answer (score 0):

Adding `Application is agent (UIElement)` to Application Target Properties and setting it to true solved the problem.. The window still does not go into the active state when another window is set as active, but clicking on the window already works and the window goes into the active state, clicking outside the window also works and the window goes into the inactive state.